# IE reads file perfectly offline but not online

Tags: internet-explorer, flash, video, iframe, server

Okay, firstly don't even ask why I am still catering to that small population using outdated Internet Explorer, I must like headaches, anyways..

On my site I have an ad I made (it's on YouTube) and I have it posted on my site. For any modern browser user I used the simple two line iframe code which works great for all except IE surprise surprise.

I got everything looking and working perfectly in IE using extensive flash code then after uploading it onto the server, it no longer loads the video even though the structure is the same, and yes, a copy of the video is where the browser can find it. How can something work great offline but utterly fall apart online?

If you have anyway to simulate an older IE (I've been in IE8 for all who wish to know) you can see it in action here [on my website](http://www.theamityblade.com/index.html) (hopefully my mobile redirect won't send you to the mobile version which it loves to do). When you click on the "Advertisement" link in the menu, a little JavaScript runs and if it sees an Internet Explorer user it directs them to the flash version of the advertisement, any others it directs to the iframe version.

I have also included the Internet Explorer page, external js file and the advert accessories in a folder which I've uploaded and that can be downloaded [on megashare](http://megashare.megahd.com.br/2Yg) for any who wishes to see the set up (the only thing I never included are the style sheets or the js which makes the menu etc as I don't see them relevant but if you believe otherwise I will upload whatever you need).

I just can't believe something that is working fine offline can break once online, it's ridiculous! Anyhow, any light you can shed on the situation would be very appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: Please look at your console if there are any errors.

Comment: (1) You cannot load `https://` content inside an `http://` site. Make sure both have matching protocol... (2) Youtube doesn't serve SWF anymore so don't know how you got your site to play Youtube via Flash plugin and even **offline** too? When you right-click on video area does it show "Adobe Flash version" anywhere in that context menu?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I gave up trying and went to bed. Thanks though for some things to check. Nowhere do I see it calling an https so I think it's okay, as for the swf, I have a swf copy of the video it summons from the public_html folder on my server, it doesn't connect to YouTube. When I right click where the video should be I have an option "About flash player 10" and a couple times I think my arrow cursor changed to the hand over it during testing. I know this is a difficult challenge and I appreciate your guidance.